# React-select container option width

Tags: reactjs, select, react-select

i' tryin the react-select library, and i like it.

I'm playing with it but i dont' understand how to change the width of the options container.

[image]

i tried to saw the documentation at [official react select](https://react-select.com/components) but i didn't find the right section about the width of the options container.

could someone kindly help me :) ?

this is my custom style right now :

```
const customStyles = {
      option: (provided, state) => ({
        ...provided,
        borderBottom: '1px solid #979797',
        width: 219,
        borderRadius: 5,
      }),
      control: () => ({
        // none of react-select's styles are passed to <Control />
        width: 219,
        border: '1px solid #979797',
        display: 'flex',
        borderRadius: '5px',
      }),
      valueContainer: (provided) => ({
        ...provided,
        width: 219,
      }),
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Menu` component is the one you want to modify:

```
menu: (provided, state) => ({
  ...provided,
  width: 50,
}),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a selector for container like

```
const colourStyles = {
  control: styles => ({ ...styles, backgroundColor: 'white' }),
  container: styles => ({ ...styles,  width: 200 })
};

<Select
  defaultValue={colourOptions[2]}
  label="Single select"
  options={colourOptions}
  styles={colourStyles}
/>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactcodesandboxerexample-yjg74?fontsize=14)